# Как получить элемент в HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Есть html, который я хочу распарсить.

```
<li data-accordion-plus="false" ....
```

Как получить данные внутри этого тега?

```
var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[???()='data-accordion-plus']").ToList();
```

Comment: У вас кроме этого тега есть что то еще? И вам надо получить все элементы с этим тегом?

Answer (score 2):

Вам не надо нечего писать лишнего в Xpath, просто укажите элемент с именем нужного атрибута.

Например имеем простой HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li data-accordion-plus="false">1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li data-accordion-plus="true">3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Далее нам нужно например получить все `li` с атрибутом `data-accordion-plus`, мы пишем:

```
var liNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@data-accordion-plus]");
```

В `liNodes` у нас будет 2 объекта. Выведем из них в консоль значения:

```
foreach (var node in liNodes)
    Console.WriteLine($"{node.InnerText.Trim()} | {node.GetAttributeValue("data-accordion-plus", false)}");
```

Результат:

1 | False
3 | True